how to escape a dot symbol
I don't know if it is possible..
on my .tex the following code:
 \def\tmp#1.#2\tmp{#1}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\MaIII\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\ARTaIII\tmp}

put on variable MaIII the content of ARTaIII variable.
So the text content on ARTIII until the first dot (.)
But if I have a dot that I would exclude from this macro, how can I do? Is it possible?
i.e. I know that I can insert a back slash simbol before some tex symbols like '%'.
Can I do something like that with a normal dot symbol?
this is the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
  \newcommand{\TaI}{D’ALEMA RICEVUTO AL QUIRINALE, POI “PELLEGRINO” SUL CORRIERE}
   \newcommand{\AaI}{\UseName{authore}}
    \newcommand{\ARTaI}{bla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla, bla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla.
    bla2 bla2 bla2bla2 bla2 bla2bla2 bla2 bla2bla2 bla2 bla2bla2 bla2 bla2bla2 bla2 bla2bla2 bla2 bla2bla2 bla2 bla2bla2 bla2 bla2 . }
    \def\tmp#1.#2\tmp{#1}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\MaI\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\ARTaI\tmp}

\begin{document}

\ARTaI\\
-------------------------text after . --------------\\
\MaI\\

\end{document}

Thank you
Renato

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

{.} will work but you really shouldn't be doing this at all, applying primitive tex delimited argument parsing to unknown user input.

do \TaI and \AaI have any connection to the question, if not why are they in the example?
