symbol % how and when can I use ir?
I would have some explanation about the % symbols: what do it is intended for? where do I have to use it?
Is there a doc that explain it?
Thank you
Renato

It is a comment everything after that to end of line is ignored, any latex tutorial should have examples of comments.. or see the [tag:percent-sign] tag here

% is used to write comments in your latex source file. The comments are to be ignored by the latex compiler. You may see this for a quick reference: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes#Adding_comments

You have used it for a comment in a post as recently as this week % Required for inserting images  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/719718/1090

I ask that because I've noted that if I leave spaces on a text line, is different that If I do not that. So I'm wondering: Do I have to close all the instruction line with a % ? Or, better, when do I have to use it?
I already knew the % symbols to use for a comment, but I've seen someone to use it in a different way

no it's the same . but aaa<newline>bbb is aaa bbb (with a space) and aaa%<newline>bbbis aaabbb as the space from end of line  is commented out.
